# Flask doesn'T work in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, virtual-environment

I have installed venv

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

I have activated it

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

I have installed Flask, while it was activated

```
sudo pip3 install Flask
```

But it doesn't work as soon as I run `python3` and then use

```
import flask
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: You usually just use `pip` and `python` in your venv. Also, please add how the venv was created and check that it is a Python 3 venv.

Comment: I think you can directly pip install flask

Comment: @KlausD. I installed `venv` as follows `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`

Answer (score 2):

Try displaying the list of the installed packages in the virtual environment. After switching to virtual environment using **source venv/bin/activate** run the command **which python** it will display the current python in use if the path points to the directory where the virtual environment is placed then it means its running fine. After this try running **pip list** to display the list of installed packages in the virtual environment. It will tell you whether flask is installed and placed inside the current environment or not.

Comment: Thanks! `which python` tells me `/root/venv/bin/python` and `which python3` tells me `/root/venv/bin/python3`. When running `pip list` it doesn't show me flask

Comment: If it does't show means it not installed while in virtual env mode run **pip install flask**  and you are good to go

Answer (score -2):

Try  `from flask import Flask`.  It's should help